# how to use jquery selectors for dinamiclly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

My question is that how to use jquery selectors for dinamiclly created element especially via ajax. Please do not mark it as a repeated question because I find alot but in vain. I did not need $().on() function here, because it does not work in my case as it take event also but i did not have an event to fire. I just want to select my dynamic selector:

```
$('#btnFileUpload').show();
```

$('#btnFileUpload') is my dynamic content with is generated via ajax request. If you want to look my whole code:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#imgPreviewContainer').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
//***** Upload File Via Ajax
$('#uploadImgModalBody').on('change','#my-file-selector',function() {
    alert('KKKKKK');
    /*var elm = $(this);
    var elmPrnt = elm.parent('.btn.btn-primary');
    var elmUploadBtn = elmPrnt.siblings('#btnFileUpload');
    var elmImg = elmPrnt.siblings('.upload-img-preview-container').find('img#imgPreviewContainer');
    $(elmUploadBtn).show();
    readURL(elm,$(elmImg));*/
    $('#btnFileUpload').show();
    readURL(this);
});

//*****Upload File Via Ajax
//#uploadImgModalBody
$('#uploadImgModalBody').on('submit','.uploadImgFrm',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $(this);
    var urlVal= frm.attr('action');

    var myFormData = new FormData();
    var _token = document.querySelector('[name=_token]').value;

    myFormData.append('profile_pic', $('#my-file-selector').prop('files')[0]);
    myFormData.append('_token', _token);
    // console.log(myFormData);
    // append other variables to data if you want: data.append('field_name_x', field_value_x);

    // myFormData.append('pictureFile', pictureInput.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: urlVal,
        processData: false, // important for image upload
        contentType: false, // important  for image upload
        dataType : 'json',
        data: myFormData,
        success: function (r) {
            if(r.success){
                // $('.btnClose').trigger('close');
                $('#showModalForUploadProfile').modal('hide');
                showMsg(r.message,window.MESSAGE_TYPE_SUCCESS)
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            var htmlStr='';
            var obj = e.responseJSON;
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty('errors')){
                // $('#jsonErrorModalTriggerer').trigger('click');
                var compulsoryInputs = ['profile_pic'];
                $('.errorsContainer').html('');
                $('.errorsContainer').show();
                $('.errorsContainer').html('<li>'+ obj.message +'</li>');
                var errors = obj.errors;
                for(var i in compulsoryInputs){
                    if(compulsoryInputs[i] in errors ){
                        var inputFieldError = errors[compulsoryInputs[i]];
                        for(var j in inputFieldError){
                            htmlStr += '<li>'+inputFieldError[j]+'</li>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $('.errorsContainer').append('<li><ul>'+htmlStr+'</ul></li>');
            }else{
                showMsg(obj.message,window.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

all events fire properly but not even single selectors working for the whole code

Comment: There is no difference between "static" elements and elements added anytime after the page has been loaded. `$('#btnFileUpload')` will query the DOM at the moment of execution in its then actual state.

Comment: @Andreas I also believe this logic but in my case when I add all content directly to the containers it works find but not with ajax.

Comment: This might be because of a race condition ... `AJAX` is asynchronous, while `jQuery` executes your selector before the `AJAX` call gets back.

Comment: so @Michel Engelen what u suggest for this problem. if it is

Comment: I don't know if you are willing to do so, but with `ES6` came the concept of `async/await` to `Javascript` which essentially waits for a function to finish, before continuing to execute the rest of the code ... so rewriting it in plain `Javascript` would be a solution (if not the only one)